# Simple way to convert Joomla 1.5 template to joomla 3.x

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla3.0

I was using joomla 1.5 on PHP4 recently my hosting provider updated to PHP5 then my joomla 1.5 crashed.
I have installed joomla 3.x 
Could anyone please tell me the simplest way to convert a joomla 1.5 template to 3.x ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pleas post here in SO and tag mootools if you need help with the Mootools scripts.

Answer (score 0):

It really all depends on how complex your template is. If you have a simple template without a lot of overrides what I would do is treat your template like a PSD and just make a fresh template based on Protostar's blank slate.

Put your `jdocs` where you want them and create the basic `less` file with the basic colors, fonts, styles that you need.

Add the template parameters if you need them in a new XML file since some of that has change.

If you have a lot of overrides again you probably want to start from scratch by copying the new core layouts and modifying them to match what you had.

Custom JS will be the biggest pain point, but if you are still running MooTools 1 you really are ready to update that.

Answer (score 0):

I used this : [SP Upgrade](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/migration-a-conversion/joomla-migration/15609) and everything works fine except some minor changes I had to make because the 1.5 version was extremely customized. The most important thing for us was the content and template which successfully migrated.